# How to get user country and timezone information from Google OAuth2 PHP Client

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using the [PHP Google API Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) to retrieve user information from a Google account using OAuth2. However, despite what [Google's documentation states](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/?csw=1#retrieving_without_query), I can not seem to access the user's *country* or *timezone* information even though the token is returned successfully and all other information can be obtained from the `userinfo.profile` scope.

I used the example code provided int heir library [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/userinfo/index.php) and if I `var_dump($user)` on line 49 of that file I get the following output (*with redaction for privacy concerns*):

```
array(10) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(21) "123" /* Redacted */
  ["email"]=>
  string(13) "XXX@gmail.com"  /* Redacted */
  ["verified_email"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["name"]=>
  string(14) "Sherif Ramadan"
  ["given_name"]=>
  string(6) "Sherif"
  ["family_name"]=>
  string(7) "Ramadan"
  ["link"]=>
  string(27) "https://plus.google.com/XXX"  /* Redacted */
  ["picture"]=>
  string(0) "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XXX-Zs/AAAAAAAAAA/AAAAAAAAA/cmBwzMLdYqM/photo.jpg"  /* Redacted */
  ["gender"]=>
  string(4) "male"
  ["locale"]=>
  string(2) "en"
}
```

As you can see no timezone or country information is available. I've tried various scopes as well such as `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login`, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me`, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`,  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`, and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo`, with no luck. They all seem to provide the same result.

I've ensured as much as I could that session/cache and other aspects were not a factor. Even renewing the auth tooken. Nothing works.

Anyone with some insight on how to retrieve this information properly through the Google API Client Library for PHP would be a great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Calendar API -> CalendarList -> list method returns a users calendar time zone which I use. I agree, a time zone should be part of plus->people->get.

Docs at: 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this information is simply not provided by Google at all and their documentation is outdated.

Comment: Agreed. The documentation is so spread out, it is almost impossible to find what you are looking for. Not to mention how poorly documented it is. How could i giant like Google fail to document their APIs? This will only hurt them, since developers are not willing to use their API.