# GMAIL API - Date search (timezone unclear)

Tags: java, gmail-api

According to https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering, if you search for a date, the PST timezone is used.

I have an email with:

```
 Date: Tue, 27 Jul 2021 06:07:49 GMT (06:07 AM)
```

If you convert this to the PST timezone, it should be:

```
Date: Mon, 26 Jul 2021 23:07:49 PST (11:07 PM)
```

Now when i use the query

```
after:2021/07/27
```

the email is found but shouldn't be according to the definition (also when i search directly on gmail.com).

For the query

```
before:2021/07/27
```

nothing is returned.

I didn't find a description yet on how to correctly search by a date and which timezones are really applied.

I'm using google-api-services-gmail-v1-rev110-1.25.0.jar.

---

Additional info:

```
String account = "myemail@gmail.com";

List<String> labelIds = new ArrayList<>();
labelIds.add("Label_mylabelid");
        
String query = "after:2021/07/27";
List<Message> timeZoneMsgs = gmail.users().messages().list(account).setQ(query).setLabelIds(labelIds).execute().getMessages();
```

I ran another test: I scheduled some emails to be sent between 11:30pm and 01:00am on the next day.

Here are the date headers (directly out of the payload) of the messages:

```
Scheduled mail 1
Date: Fri, 24 Dec 2021 23:30:00 +0100

Scheduled mail 2
Date: Fri, 24 Dec 2021 23:45:00 +0100

Scheduled mail 3
Date: Sat, 25 Dec 2021 00:00:00 +0100

Scheduled mail 4
Date: Sat, 25 Dec 2021 00:15:00 +0100

Scheduled mail 5
Date: Sat, 25 Dec 2021 00:30:00 +0100

Scheduled mail 6
Date: Sat, 25 Dec 2021 00:45:00 +0100

Scheduled mail 7
Date: Sat, 25 Dec 2021 01:00:00 +0100
```

If I search with

```
after:2021/12/25
```

directly on gmail.com - i get the messages 3 to 7 and if i search with

```
before:2021/12/25
```

I get 1 and 2, which is both correct.

BUT when I do the same with the java call, I only get message 7 (1am) for "after:2021/12/25" and messages 1-6 for "before:2021/12/25".

---

Another example:

I also tried searching with the epoch time in UTC:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
calendar.clear();
calendar.set(2021, Calendar.DECEMBER, 25);
long secondsSinceEpoch = calendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L; // 1640390400
```

Here, I get the same result for direct gmail.com search and java search: Message 7 (1pm) for "after:1640390400" and 1-6 for "before:1640390400".

If I try this for PST (1640419200), I get no messages for "after:1640419200" and all of them for "before:1640419200".

Comment: From what I see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list), you can use `q` with the same format as Gmail Search Box. Can you check if the messages appear under this conditions?   Take into account that `Gmail` stores the time as UTC an after is translated to your local time.

Comment: It would be helpful if you also check the `Date` header inside the payload.

Comment: @Emel I am using q for the query; I updated my original question with some more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering) states:

> To specify accurate dates for other timezones pass the value in seconds instead.

This is a Java sample code, is tested and working .For the example I get all the messages from yesterday 23:00 to today 13:00. **Tip**: You can use `me` as a keyword to your email account:

```java
long startTimeEpoch = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-12-27T23:00",
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
long endTimeEpoch = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-12-28T13:00",
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);
String query = String.format("after:%s before:%s", startTimeEpoch, endTimeEpoch);
String account = "me";
System.out.println(query);
List < String > labelIds = new ArrayList < > ();
labelIds.add("Label_mylabelid");
List < Message > timeZoneMsgs = service.users().messages().list(account)
    .setQ(query)
    .execute()
    .getMessages();
System.out.println(timeZoneMsgs);
```

###### Documentation:

- [Gmail API Javadoc documentation](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-gmail/latest/index.html)
- [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)
- [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: So if Gmail stores the time in UTC and I want all emails starting from e.g. 26.12.2021 it should be:
  long startTimeEpoch = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-12-26T00:00",
       DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")).toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC);

--> 1640476800

If I use this, I only get emails starting from 26.12.2021 01:00am instead of 00:00am ...

Comment: ah nevermind .. that was my bad. 26.12.2021 00:00 in my timezone is 25.12.2021 23:00 in UTC. So to use the correct account timezone, I should apparently get it via the calendar api according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18325906/how-to-get-user-country-and-timezone-information-from-google-oauth2-php-client . Thank you!